# Java, set variable during time to half

Tags: java

I have a timer that resets every 3 seconds. During these 3 seconds, I want the velocity of the player to be halved every time there is a swipe. After the 3 seconds is up, the velocity should be reset to max velocity again. Some pseudocode:

```
  maxVelocity = 5;
  if(timer >=0)
     current swipe = maxVelocity;
     next swipe = current swipe / 2;
  when timer resets(the next swipe will be max velocity)
```

Right now I am using a float value for the timer and subtracting based on the time of the application running, but I cannot figure out how to halve the velocity while the timer is counting down.

Comment: The pseudo-logic is roughly equivalent to: `if (timer >= 0) { next swipe = (maxVelocity / 2) }`. Per the problem description the *current velocity of the player* should be halved.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo-code does exactly what you want. In Java, here is the exact code:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class HalfReset {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        final float max = 5;
        final float[] current = { 5.0f };
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                current[0] = max;
            }
        }
        Swipe.addSwipeListener(new Runnable() { // Or however the swipe works
            public void run() {
                current[0] /= 2.0f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```